# merging 2 arrays in ascending order (leetcode)

Tags: java, arrays, function

```
class Solution{
public static void merge(int[] nums1, int m, int[] nums2, int n) {
    int[] result = new int[m + n];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (i < m && j < n) {
        if (nums1[i] < nums2[j]) {
            result[k++] = nums1[i++];
        } else {
            result[k++] = nums2[j++];
        }
    }
    while (i < m) {
        result[k++] = nums1[i++];
    }
    while (j < n) {
        result[k++] = nums2[j++];
    }
    System.arraycopy(result, 0, nums1, 0, m + n);
  }
}
```

why do i have to copy the result array in nums1 ?
And is there any better alternative for this ?

I tried to print the result array directly but its not working it is showing time exceeded.

Comment: Do not tag this as `dsa`.  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.

Comment: From _leetcode_, "... The final sorted array should not be returned by the function, but instead be stored inside the array nums1. To accommodate this, nums1 has a length of m + n ...".

Comment: You failed to let us know about a requirement: The result of the merge *must* be in `nums1`. See https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-sorted-array/

Comment: Using an intermediate array to hold the results of the merge and then copying the intermediate to `nums1` is the easiest way to meet the requirement that the result is to be in the `nums1` argument. `nums1 = result;` won't work because Java is pass by value : `nums1` is a *local* reference variable. In the `Solution.merge` method, changing the Object it points to will not change what the reference that was used as an argument in the calling program points to.

Comment: I don't  understand this part of your question:  *"I tried to print the result array directly but its not working it is showing time exceeded"*.   If you are asking for help in that area, *"it is not working"* doesn't tell us anything. And, we need context for *"it is showing time exceeded"*.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below code :

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array1 = {1, 3, 5, 7};
        int[] array2 = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};

        int[] mergedArray = mergeArrays(array1, array2);

        // Print the merged array
        for (int element : mergedArray) {
            System.out.print(element + " ");
        }   
    }
    
    public static int[] mergeArrays(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
        int size1 = array1.length;
        int size2 = array2.length;
        int[] mergedArray = new int[size1 + size2];

        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

        // Merge arrays while elements are present in both arrays
        while (i < size1 && j < size2) {
            if (array1[i] < array2[j]) {
                mergedArray[k++] = array1[i++];
            } else {
                mergedArray[k++] = array2[j++];
            }
        }

        // If there are remaining elements in array1, add them to the result array
        while (i < size1) {
            mergedArray[k++] = array1[i++];
        }

        // If there are remaining elements in array2, add them to the result array
        while (j < size2) {
            mergedArray[k++] = array2[j++];
        }

        return mergedArray;
    }
}
```

> Refer the working sample [here](https://onlinegdb.com/O2HAPFN6M)

Comment: This doesn't actually meet the O/P's requirements. The misunderstanding is the result of the O/P failing to make it clear the merged array result must be placed in the elements of the `nums1` argument.